# TypeError: undefined has no properties loginClicked

Tags: reactjs

I have two components TodoApp and LoginComponent . The TodoApp component includes all the components and is the main one . I want to do a page redirect in LoginComponent when login is successful .

```
import  React , {Component,useState} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import AuthenticationService from './AuthenticationService.js'
import AuthenticatedRoute from './AuthenticatedRoute.jsx'

const TodoApp  =()=>{


    const [isUserLoggedIn, setisUserLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    const userLoggedInHandler = (value) => {
        setisUserLoggedIn(value);
    }

        return(
            <div className="TodoApp">
                <Router>
                    <>
                        <HeaderComponent user={isUserLoggedIn}/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => (
                                <LoginComponent {...props} isAuthed={userLoggedInHandler} />
                            )}></Route>
                            <Route path="/login"  render={(props) => (
                                <LoginComponent {...props} isAuthed={userLoggedInHandler} />
                            )}></Route>
                        </Switch>
                        <FooterComponent/>
                    </>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )


}
```

```
const LoginComponent =(props)=> {

    const [username, setusername] = useState('in28minutes');
    const [password, setpassword] = useState('');
    const [hasLoginFailed, sethasLoginFailed] = useState(false);
    const [isUserLoggedIn, setshowSuccessMessage] = useState(false);

    const nameChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setusername(event.target.value);

    };

    const passwordChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setpassword(event.target.value);

    };

    const loginClicked=()=> {
        if (username === "in28minutes" && password === "dummy") {
            AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password);
            sethasLoginFailed(false)
            setshowSuccessMessage(true)
            props.isAuthed(true)
            props.history.push(`/welcome/${this.state.username}`)

        } else {
            setshowSuccessMessage(false)
            sethasLoginFailed(true)
        }
    }

        return (

                <>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <div className="container">
                    {hasLoginFailed && <div className="alert alert-warning">Invalid Credentials</div>}
                    User Name : <input type="text" name="username" value={username}
                                       onChange={nameChangeHandler}/>
                    Password : <input type="password" name="password" value={password}
                                      onChange={passwordChangeHandler}/>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={loginClicked}>Login</button>
                </div>
                </>

        )

}
```

When I click on the login button on the login component I get this error

```
TypeError: undefined has no properties
loginClicked
src/components/todo/TodoApp.jsx:182

  179 |     sethasLoginFailed(false)
  180 |     setshowSuccessMessage(true)
  181 |     props.isAuthed(true)
> 182 |     props.history.push(`/welcome/${this.state.username}`)
```

actually I want to redirect to this url - /welcome/${this.state.username}
Any suggestion of how to achieve it ?

Comment: I believe you should just use `username` instead of `this.state.username`

Comment: I modified the entire code except that url . Thanks for the suggestion .

Answer (score 1):

You are using a function component with the `useState()` hook, therefore you don't access the state via `this.state`.

As you have the username state as:

```js
const [username, setusername] = useState("");
```

You can use this to push the location to the history:

```js
// just username, not this.state.username
props.history.push(`/welcome/${username}`)
```

Comment: I modified the entire code except that url . Thanks for the suggestion .